# How to implement onkeyup function with a specific key

Tags: javascript, html, game-physics, keycode, onkeyup

I am trying to create a basic platformer game, and I'm working on the gravity section. I am using some if myGameArea.keys statements to allow the player to move their character forwards and backwards, and up. I am using an accelerate function to stop gravity when the up key is pressed, but I can't make it start again when the key is lifted. I know how to implement the onkeyup function (onkeyup = function();) but I don't know how to add it to my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
      canvas {
        border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="startGame()">
    <script>
      var myGamePiece;

      function startGame() {
        myGameArea.start();
        myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 240);
      }

      var myGameArea = {
        canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
        start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, 
        document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
        myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
      })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keyup");
      })
     },
       clear : function(){
       this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
     }
   }

    function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
      this.type = type;
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.speedX = 0;
      this.speedY = 0;
      this.gravity = 0.05;
      this.gravitySpeed = 0;
      this.update = function() {
         ctx = myGameArea.context;
         ctx.fillStyle = color;
         ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
         }
      this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
      }
      this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
          this.y = rockbottom;
        }
      }
    }

   function updateGameArea() {
      myGameArea.clear();
      myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
      myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
      myGamePiece.gravity = 0.1;
      if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.speedX = -2; 
      }
      if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.speedX = 2; 
      }
      if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {accelerate(-0.2)}
      myGamePiece.newPos();
      myGamePiece.update();
     }

    function accelerate(n) {
      myGamePiece.gravity = n;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is only a small portion of the code. If anyone would like the full amount, comment below to tell me, please. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have a `keydown` event someplace to detect the key press? Seems like that's where you would want to put your `keyup` event registration too.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't realised, but here is in a separate part of the code. I will edit to add this, and I'll try change some things there.

Comment: I do also have a keyup part to it. I'll see how I can use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues:

In your `keyup` event handler, you have:

```
myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keyup");
```

But this will set the property value to `true`. You want `false`, so just do:

```
myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = false;
```

(BTW, this error was not there in one of your previous question versions, where you had `(e.type == "keydown")`.

You can also simply set to `true` in the `keydown` handler (but there was no error there).

Secondly, the `gravitySpeed` keeps increasing even when you hit the bottom. This will make that value incredible great, and the counter accelaration when pressing the up key will not have any visible effect, unless you wait long enough. Instead, reset `gravitySpeed here::

```
 this.y = rockbottom;
 this.gravitySpeed = 0; // <----
```

See it run:

```js
var myGamePiece;

function startGame() {
    myGameArea.start();
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 240);
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
    keys: [], // <--- just initialise here
    start: function() {
        window.focus();
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 180;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, 
        document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = true; // <---
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = false; // <---
        })
    },
    clear : function(){
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.gravity = 0.05;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0; // <----
        }
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
    myGamePiece.gravity = 0.1;
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.speedX = -2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.speedX = 2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {accelerate(-0.2)}
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function accelerate(n) {
    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}


window.onload = startGame;
```

```css
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I do already have this value set in another variable. I have tried what you suggested, but I'm afraid it doesn't work. To avoid further misconceptions, I will edit the entire code into my question. Thanks though!

Comment: That's why we ask to provide enough, but minimal code, that enables us to *reproduce* your issue ;-)

Comment: Updated my answer, now that it is clear that you have a `gravitySpeed` variable, which was not in your question before, yet it is at the cause of the problem.